# How do I find out if a button was pressed in an array of buttons

Tags: java, swing, jframe, jbutton

Im doing sth like the game battleship. I have a 2 dimensional array with buttons so I have a 10*10 field of them. How do I find out if a button was pressed and which button it was?

Comment: Either give each button its own unique `actionCommand` string, which will be included in the `ActionEvent` that will be passed to your action listener's `actionPerformed` method.  Or, use `getSource()`  on the `ActionEvent` to obtain the actual `JButton`, and then look for the matching `JButton` in your 10x10 array of `JButton`s.

Comment: getSource returns a reference to the JButton that was pressed.  If you need more info from the buton: Extend the JButton class and then add your class to the array vs JButton.  Add method(s) to your class to return its location.  Pass and save the location in your class's constructor.